# Entity Framework Core : Select Parent and just one Child

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I have a Parent and Child class defined as per usual:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ParentName { get; set; }
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ChildName { get; set; }
}
```

I have `ParentId` and `ChildId` to query with.

I need to select the parent and **only 1** child matching the `ChildId`.

How do I do this in one query?

TIA

Comment: How Child is related to Parent?

Comment: Child is a child of parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you are looking for is called [Filtered Include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include).

In your case the code will be the following:

```cs
var parent = dbContext.Parents
                      .Include(p => p.Children.Where(c => c.Id == childId))
                      .SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == parentId)
```

Comment: Thanks @Neistow this worked a charm. Apologies for accepting this late...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can get both in one query, but below should work.

```
var foundParentEnum =
    from curParent in ListOfParents
    where curParent.Id == parentIdLookingFor
    select curParent;

var foundParent = foundParentEnum.FirstOrDefault();
var foundChild = foundParent.Children.FirstOrDefault();
```

If you want to find the child in one query.

```
var foundChildEnum =
    from curParent in ListOfParents
    where curParent.Id == parentIdLookingFor
    select curParent.Children.FirstOrDefault();
```

Added a [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DitmgI) to see it working.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).